# Does HttpMessageConverter<T> converts automatically or do we need to specify in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, http-headers

I am working on Spring in java i have come across HttpMessageConverter for converting the response type ,to some other type

I want to know some thing about this class here is an example

There is a server and a client , Server sends response in some format (say XML) and client wants the response in other format (say Json) if client sends in headers like

```
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

Does HttpMessageConverter will automatically convert the type of response to Json or else in the client code do we need to say HttpMessageConverter to convert the Response Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Server sends response in some format (say XML) and client wants the
>   response in other format (say Json) if client sends in headers like

There is a concept called *Content Negotiation* or *Conneg* for short. You as a client specify your expected content type, language, encoding, etc. with HTTP headers like `Accept`, `Accept-Language`, `Accept-Encoding`, etc. and send that request to the server and the server responds accordingly. So, if you set `Accept` header to `application/json` and server *only* can serve `application/xml` content type, it will return a `406 Not Acceptable` HTTP Client Error. *Basically it says i may have the resource you want but not with the requested representation*.

If you have access to the server code, you can change your `Data Transfer Object`s in a way that spring could convert them to `xml` or `json`. Simply when you annotate each method with `@ResponseBody`, that method's return value could be converted by the default `HttpMessageConverter`s:

> You convert the request body to the method argument by using an
>   HttpMessageConverter. HttpMessageConverter is responsible for
>   converting from the HTTP request message to an object and converting
>   from an object to the HTTP response body. The
>   RequestMappingHandlerAdapter supports the @RequestBody annotation with
>   the following default HttpMessageConverters:
>
> - ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converts byte arrays.
> - StringHttpMessageConverter converts strings.
> - FormHttpMessageConverter converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.
> - SourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from a javax.xml.transform.Source

Also, if you add Jackson 2 library to your classpath, `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` will take care of converting to/from JSON.

But, if you haven't access to the server code and server only serves XML, the only option would be getting XML from server and converting it to JSON manually.

Comment: So even if i have kept headers headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

Does HttpMessageConverter automatically convert the response type to json at client side or do i need to use HttpMessageConverter at client code to convert to json

Comment: If you set `Accept` to `application/json` and your service is only serve `aplication/xml`, there would be pretty good chance that you'll get `415` HTTP error. I guess it's better to set `Accept` to to `application/xml`, then fetch xml and deserialize to a `DTO` that is convertible to JSON by, say, jackson

Comment: Then what does default HttpMessageConverters mean or what does they do

Comment: Suppose you have server method, say, `doStuff(Resource res)`. If a client send a `POST` request to this service, default converters will try to convert  the request body to an instance of `Resource` class. Same would happen for clients. What you want is a way to convert XML to JSON by this converters which kinda absurd.